# Recode variables R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
x1=c(0,2,1,3,0)
x2=c(3,2,0,0,1)
x3=c(0,2,1,0,0)
d=cbind(x1,x2,x3)
```

and I'd like to replace the 0's in x1 and x2 with 4 (excluding x3) so that the data data looks like:

```
> d
     x1 x2 x3
[1,]  4  3  0
[2,]  2  2  2
[3,]  1  4  1
[4,]  3  4  0
[5,]  4  1  0
```

How can I do this in the base package?

Comment: `d[, 1:2][d[, 1:2]==0] <- 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do so. Here is one:

```
d[,1:2][d[,1:2]==0] <- 4
```

The first square brackets tell R to apply the operation on the first and second column. The second brackets tell R the condition (Where the first or second column is "0"). Well and behind the arrow you have the new value you want to assign to the entries that met the condition.

Technically speaking, the `d[,1:2]==0` part creates a Boolean matrix (with two columns) where the entries are `TRUE` , when the respective field in d is "0". Then this Boolean matrix is applied to the first two columns of d as a logical index for the assignment of 4.